# 20 verticies of degree 25, 300 verticies of degree 5, prove there exists a path.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Hi, I'm having a hard time visualizing this graph theory problem.

Let G be a graph that has $20$ vertices of degree $25$ and $300$ vertices of degree $5$, and 
no other vertices. Prove that for every vertex $x$ of degree $25$ there exists a path in G from $x$ to a vertex of degree $5.$

Comment: It's too easy like this: there are at least 6 edges from $x$ to $B:=\{300$ vertices of degree $5\}$, these can be viewed as paths of length 1. Probably both $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary, no?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the statement is false, that is, that there is a vertex *v* of degree $25$ such that there is no path from *v* to any vertex of degree $5$. Then *v* cannot be adjacent to any vertex of degree $5$, so all of *v*'s $25$ neighbors have degree $25$. But there are only $19$ other vertices of degree $25$, so *v* cannot have $25$ such neighbors. Thus *v* has a neighbor of degree $5$, and thus there is a path from *v* to a vertex of degree $5$.